# Finding area bound by polar graph

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates, area

> Find the area on the inside of the curve $ r^2 = 4\cos(14\theta)$, but on the outside of the unit circle $r = 1.$

I tried finding the area of the part of the leaves which is outside the unit circle, by solving the following integral:

$$
\frac12 14\int_\frac{-π}{42}^\frac{π}{42} 4\cos(14\theta)\,\text{d}\theta
$$

but I obtained the wrong answer.

Comment: I don't see why my method doesen't work. With my integration limits i should only get the part of the leaves that I want. When subtracting the area of the unit circle i get $$ \frac{\pi}{28}\over 2\pi$$ and the answer should have $\pi$ in it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha=\arccos(1/4)/14$ so that $4\cos(14\theta)\geq 1$ for $-\alpha\leq\theta\leq\alpha$.
To the integral
$$\frac 12\int_{-\alpha}^\alpha r^2\,\mathrm d\theta$$
you have to subtract the area of circular sector $ACB$ which equals $\alpha$.
Thus the required area is given by
\begin{align}
14\left(\frac 12\int_{-\alpha}^\alpha r^2\,\mathrm d\theta-\alpha\right)
&=14\left(\frac{\sqrt{15}}{14}-\alpha\right)\\
&=\sqrt{15}-14\alpha\\
&=\sqrt{15}-\arccos(1/4)
\end{align}

[image]